# How to monitor Apache Flume agents status?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I know the Enterprise (Cloudera for example) way, by using a CM (via browser) or by Cloudera REST API one can access monitoring and configuring facilities.

But how to schedule (run and rerun) flume agents livecycle, and monitor their running/failure status without CM? Are there such things in the Flume distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried adding `flume.monitoring.type/port` to `flume-ng` on start. And it completely fits my needs.

Lets create a simple agent `a1` for example. Which listens on `localhost:44444` and logs to console as a sink:

```
# flume.conf
a1.sources = s1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks = d1

a1.sources.s1.channels = c1
a1.sources.s1.type = netcat
a1.sources.s1.bind = localhost
a1.sources.s1.port = 44444

a1.sinks.d1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.d1.type = logger

a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 100
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 10
```

Run it with additional parameters `flume.monitoring.type/port`:

```
flume-ng agent -n a1 -c conf -f flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console -Dflume.monitoring.type=http -Dflume.monitoring.port=44123
```

And then monitor output in browser at `localhost:44123/metrics`

```
{"CHANNEL.c1":{"ChannelCapacity":"100","ChannelFillPercentage":"0.0","Type":"CHANNEL","EventTakeSuccessCount":"570448","ChannelSize":"0","EventTakeAttemptCount":"570573","StartTime":"1567002601836","EventPutAttemptCount":"570449","EventPutSuccessCount":"570448","StopTime":"0"}}
```

Just try some load:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=1024 bs=1024 | base64 | nc localhost 44444
```

Answer (score 1):

Flume's JSON Reporting API can be used to monitor health and performance.
[Link](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#json-reporting)